# Cache invalidation while caching database in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, django-johnny-cache

I am fairly new to the concept of caching, trying to use a custom middleware to cache DB queries in django. I tried using Johnny cache but its cache invalidation logic isn't that optimised in my use case.

I have a huge table, from which multiple read/write queries are being made. Johnny cache reads into the cache and invalidates it if any write query is made on the particular table.

**[Johnny Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html)**

> "Avoiding the database at all costs was not a goal, so different ordering clauses on the same dataset are considered different queries. Since invalidation happens at the table level, any table having been modified makes the cached query inaccessible"

I want to have a more specific cache invalidation in my case. What are some other standard ways to do this?